# C# How can i split a string on first number?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following string
`"ABCD EFG 201 E"` i want to split it on the first number that it founds a digit
and return both strings Ex. `"ABCD EFG"` and `"201 E"`

i tried Regex.Split and other stuff but i don't get it. can someone help me please?
Thanks, Best Regards.

Comment: find the first index containing a number and split at that index

Comment: `Regex.Split(input, @"(\d.*)")` should do it.  Will return `ABCD EFG ` (with a trailing space) and `201 E`.  You didn't actually describe a rule that justifies why you omitted the space following the `G`.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you tried what the problem you have with your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not using regex cos I dont really like them -  story goes "you have a problem, you decide to use regex on it, you now have 2 problems"

```
 char[] digits = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
 string s = "ABCD EFG 201 E";
 var idx = s.IndexOfAny(digits);
 if (idx !=-1){
     var first = s.Substring(0,idx);
     var second = s.Substring(idx);
 }
```

Comment: yep that work this is my final code

string text= "ABCD EFG 201 E";
  Console.WriteLine(viaje);
  var letters = text.Substring(0,text.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'}));
  var code = text.Substring(text.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'}));

Comment: @AlejandroRodriguez why do the IndexOfAny twice, why force the creation of that array twice? I will take my points but - ouch

Answer (score 1):

Using `Regex`, you can do it like below :

```
    string Text = "ABCD EFG 201 E";  
    string[] digits = Regex.Split(Text, @"(\d.*)");  
    foreach (string value in digits)  
        Console.WriteLine(value);
```

[Code Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F2eJzu)